# How to get Details by jquery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html code of dropdown choice with checkbox like this:

```
<ul id="channelFieldUL" class="dropdown-menu channelFieldUL">
   <li class="sourceFieldRecordClass" onclick="goNext("account")">
       <a class>
       <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="account" class="apiFieldRecord" id="account0">" account "
       </label>
       </a>
   </li>
   ... 
     //another li
<ul>
```

then the function :

```
function goNext(source){
   //content
}
```

what i want to ask is, what do i need to put in the function to get all the `<ul>` option, and then uncheck the other options beside selected option?

P.S: i tried using `.parent()` or `.closest`, but it doesnt work (maybe because wrong usage)

Comment: Use type [radio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio) instead of checkbox. Give them the same `name` and you will be able to select only a single one. No need for JS

Comment: that will change the major of the code then. The original code was not mine, but i need to add function to handle those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use query selector to get the all the li elements inside ul element

like

```
    let lis = document.getElementById('channelFieldUL').getElementsByTagName('li');
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the advice and i will try this. also, can you explain further on how to unselect the other options, please (ex : what getter should i use, etc) ?.

Comment: please see the above answer i have added the logic how can you select and un select the particular check box.

Comment: @IhtishamTanveer hi, thanks for the answer. i will try it !

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```js
$('.apiFieldRecord').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $('.apiFieldRecord').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
  }
})
```

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="channelFieldUL" class="dropdown-menu channelFieldUL">
   <li class="sourceFieldRecordClass">
       <a class>
       <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="account" class="apiFieldRecord" id="account1">account 1
       </label>
       </a>
   </li>
   <li class="sourceFieldRecordClass">
       <a class>
       <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="account"  class="apiFieldRecord" id="account2">account 2
       </label>
       </a>
   </li>
   <li class="sourceFieldRecordClass">
       <a class>
       <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="account"  class="apiFieldRecord" id="account3">account 3
       </label>
       </a>
   </li>
<ul>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice, but i forgot to add that the context of the function is that when i click option AROUND the TEXT/Checkbox it will do as clicking ON the text/checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

you can select the specific input of li element and can check and uncheck them like this

```
document.getElementById("checkbox").checked = true;

// Uncheck
document.getElementById("checkbox").checked = false;
```